# How to eloquently calculate the mean of means using group by function in R?

Tags: r

I try to group by year and then calculate the average of means, but I don't know the fastest way to do it and the way I do it gives me an error.

First I calculate how many rows per year the table has:

```
avg_awarded_moves_year <- imdb_globes %>% group_by(year_film) %>% 
                                          tally()
```

And then again use transmute function to add the table the average per year.

```
avg_awarded_moves_year <- imdb_globes %>% group_by(year_film) %>% 
                                          transmute(average_per_year = 
                                                      sum(averageRating)/avg_awarded_moves_year$n)
```

The error I encounter: `Error: Column "average_per_year" must be length 12 (the group size) or one, not 76`

I can bet that there is a faster and more eloquent way to do it. I tried to divide the sum by "n()" , but it didn't work as well. I don't want to use mean function because the sample consists o means already.

Comment: Try `average_per_year = mean(averageRating, na.rm = T)` directly to your code. Instead of `transmute` you may want to use `summarise`

Comment: @Neel ok, but is it ok to apply the mean function to mean variables?

Comment: yes definitely. you just want to find mean of means.